# Trying to write a batch file to handle vanilla builds for me, installing generic apps(google, zoom, outlook, etc), but want it to handle more

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I have a vanilla batch file already that installs all the necessary apps. I'm trying to add to this file and have it assign the computers name under "domain join", uninstall certain apps, turn on certain features, etc.

As of right now, I only tried `wmic product where name "product name" call uninstall`

This isn't working when I try `wmic product where name "'%%Microsoft 365 - en-us%%'"` but it's also not working when I try to uninstall something simply from Control Panel through cmd.

I get the error `No Instance(s) Available.`

Comment: Your command is incomplete you need to use a [WQL operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-operators), _(I presume your first example should include `=` and your second `LIKE`)_. I would also presume that your wildcards are excessive, in that a leading wildcard is not necessary, because the matching `Name` string will begin with `Microsoft`

Comment: so delete my entire question? I figured out how to uninstall what I wanted though. does it not require an update?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to uninstall what I wanted, (uninstall Microsoft <s>Office</s> 365).

Here it is, if anyone wants to use it as well:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeClickToRun.exe" scenario=install scenariosubtype=ARP sourcetype=None productstoremove=O365HomePremRetail.16_en-us_x-none culture=en-us version.16=16.0
```

Comment: Whilst I applaud you for providing a method of achieving your intended task, the answer above does not solve the `WMIC` "No Instance(s) Available" problem you posed in the question area. The solution to that was spelled out in my initial comment, which you decided to ignore, and shown in several existing answers already on this site. Remember your question title itself clearly lists applications, not just a single and specific Microsoft unistallation. Technically what you've done is to provide an answer to a question you did not ask.